# O que há de errado no meu Ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, json

Meu código não tem retorno e não consigo descobrir o por que.

index.php

```
<form id="login" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Usuário ou email" />
        <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Senha" />
        <button onclick="enviar()" type="submit">Entrar</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function enviar() {
        var formula = $('#login').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dateType: 'json',
            data: formula,  
            url: 'http://localhost/teste/enviar.php',
            success: function(data) {
                if (data == 1) {
                    alert("OK");
                    window.location = "";
                }

                if(data == 0) {
                    alert("Nada OK");
                    window.location = "";
                }
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error.responseText);
            }
        })
        return false;
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
```

Enviar.php

```
<?php
$resposta = 1;
echo (json_encode($resposta));
```

Comment: ,o que você está querendo dizer com "minha função não tem retorno?",o retorno seria entrar em algum "if",ou retornar "falso"?,explique um pouco mais do seu problema

Comment: Ele deveria estar alertando 'OK', já que estou retornando 1

Comment: acabei de testar aqui e funcionou perfeitamente, talvez o problema seja no seu arquivo do "jQuery",você tem certeza que está nesse local?

Comment: Já viu o console do navegador? Será que a ordem que o carregamento do jQuery e a falta do `$(document).ready` não pode ser o problema?

Comment: Tente retirar o `json_encode`, deixe apenas `echo $resposta;`. Apenas objetos e arrays devem ser transformados para json.

Comment: Cancele o `submit`normal, e chame sua função no `onSubmit` assim: `<form ..... onSubmit="enviar(); return false;" >`

Answer (score 4):

Tu estás utilizando "dateType", sendo que o correto é "dataType".